# feature importance between two data distributions

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-extraction

I have two textual datasets collected from different domains (Twitter and Reddit).

I extracted a set of features in the same way from these two datasets, one of these features as an example called X_positive.

How could I know if the feature X_positive is more representative (exists more) in one of the datasets?

Comment: Can you please share how did you extract these features?

Comment: @DaFanat .. frequency of specific cue words

Comment: So your feature is a count on how many times specific words appear in each of the data sets?

Comment: @DaFanat ,, yes .. how many times specific words appear in the tweets as an example ..  each of the datasets consist of N records of tweets/reddits posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents:
I can think of several ways calculating specific terms repressiveness:

1) Calculating rate of documents(tweets/posts) where these terms appear more than 
1(or X > 1) times. You can decide on X by looking at the distribution of frequency per document.
2) Calculating terms [TF-IDF](http://www.tfidf.com/) score per each document and aggregating across all documents. Aggregating across all document  depends on your need and what you mean by representative.
3) Calculating terms appearance rate - how many times these terms appear divided by total number of words in the corpus(possibly after subtracting stop words).